# Android viewpager glass background

Tags: android, background, android-viewpager

I have implemented viewpager. How can i give it a glass effect background, like the one we have for android applications list.

Comment: Which list do you mean? Picture? Version?

Comment: you can set alpha color for your view or image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or i think you can set your background colour either in xml as

```
android:background="#80xxxxxx"
```

80 is the hexa-decimal equivalent of 128 fpr the alpha value to be translucent

otherwise, in java file

```
bg.setColor(Color.argb(128, xxx, xxx, xxx));
```

hope this helps...

Comment: where to set this color? I have set the same but getting white color always

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a background for your Activity, in which you can see things at the back side of your Activity. For this, you can use a "Translucent" theme for your activity and also set a Background Image of your activity which can be a little blurry.