# is it possible to set transparent for viewpager of android

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, transparent

I want to make transparent for `ViewPager`, but I can't find any way to get it (It always has WHITE color, not transparent)

My layout: main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout for first fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the layout for second fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I already set transparent for both background of `ViewPager` and layouts for fragments. But it's always WHITE.

So, Is it possible to set transparent for `ViewPager`? Can you explain it for me (if any). Any suggestion will be appreciate. Thank you.

EDIT:
I used the default theme for activity:

[image]

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: try this, hopeit help : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9995621/5723796)

Comment: I already set transparent for background color of each *.xml

Comment: Are you already using "Translucent" theme in your parent layout? What is your wallpaper color in parent LinearLayout ?

Comment: @ErAcube I don't understand "using Translucent" mean :(. The wallpaper is an image

Comment: @vandaics What is you Activity's theme?

Comment: @Karakuri I used default theme. I edited this theme in the question.

Comment: @vandics do you mean see through activity?

Comment: @AwaisKing No, Only see through `ViewPager`. Not transparent activity

Comment: @vandaics use Styles Theme

Comment: @AwaisKing what do you mean? I can't get it

Comment: @vandaics styles.xml and themes

Comment: @AwaisKing can you write down your suggest as an answer? I already try the answer below of Karakuri.

Comment: @vandaics What is `@drawable/wallpaper`? Is it a png image? Is it an XML drawable?

Comment: @Kafakuri, it is an image. Something like that: http://phandroid.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/corvo.jpg

Comment: @vandaics like this: http://i.imgur.com/EUxt25x.png ??

Comment: @AwaisKing wow, that's right, viewpager above an background image

Answer (score 2):

Awais Soomro answer didn't work, so I've come up with this:

Fragment.java

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

or even...

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code to this:
[image: VIEWPAGER]

**MyFragment.java**:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

**my_fragment.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#00ffffff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
        android:textColor="#69f0ae"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main.java**:

```
FragmentPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter = new FragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()) {
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return new MyFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
};
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

**main_activity.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably not the background color of the ViewPager.  It's probably the view that's inflated by the adapter that ViewPager is using.  Change the background color of that view.